# Data fetch from json

Tags: android, json, web-services

First time i am doing this so need help. I have a json file 
https://api.github.com/gists/public
and i want to fetch its data only "login" and "id" under user tag .Please help .

Looking at the examples i tried fetching the data from the following code and putting the content in log but the log content and the content in the url is different .

```
try {
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
            request.setURI(new URI("https://api.github.com/gists/public"));
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
            InputStream ips = response.getEntity().getContent();
            BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(ips,
                    "UTF-8"));

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String s;
            while (true) {
                s = buf.readLine();
                if (s == null || s.length() == 0)
                    break;
                sb.append(s);
                JSONArray ja = new JSONArray(s);

                for (int i = 0; i < ja.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject jo = (JSONObject) ja.get(i);
                    //items.add(jo.getString("text"));
                    Log.v("json", "json object : " + jo.getString("user"));
                }
                Log.v("json", "json file : " + sb);
            }
            buf.close();
            ips.close();

        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            // any cleanup code...
        }
```

Comment: also place your JSON ARRAY here that will more clear how to resolve it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually `"user"` is a `JSONObject`, So firstly you have to get that `JSONObject` and then fetch the `String`s in it. Do this in your `for` loop.

```
JSONObject obj = jo.getJSONObject("user");
String login = obj.getString("login");
String id = obj.getString("id");
```